# How can i get the string representation from queryset in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the queryset like this

`qs = User.objects.all()`

I am converting to dict like this

`qs.values('id', 'username')`

but instead of username i want to get the string representation.

something like

`qs.values('id', '__str__')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot, `values` can only fetch values stored in the database, the string representation is not stored in the database, it is computed in Python.

What you could do is:

```
qs = User.objects.all()
# Compute the values list "manually".
data = [{'id': user.id, '__str__': str(user)} for user in qs]

# You may use a generator to not store the whole data in memory,
# it may make sense or not depending on the use you make
# of the data afterward.
data = ({'id': user.id, '__str__': str(user)} for user in qs)
```

**Edit:** on second thought, depending on how your string representation is computed, it may be possible to use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/expressions/) to achieve the same result.