# In Django, how to annotate a queryset with the string representation each object?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a view which inherits from Django's `ListView` and uses a search form through a `SearchMixin`. Here is the (simplified) view:

```
class ListBase(DashboardAccessMixin, SearchMixin):
    queryset = CheckInType.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        query = self.search_data('q')

        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query))

        return queryset


class CheckInTypeList(ListBase, ListView):
    template_name = 'check_in_types/index.html'
```

The template, however, does not actually show the `{{ object.title }}`, but shows just `{{ object }}`, which corresponds to the string representation of the `CheckInType`. This is defined as follows:

```
class CheckInType(TimeStampedModel, TimingMixIn):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    # Timing
    is_prenatal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    min_weeks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    max_weeks = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.title:
            return self.title
        else:
            prenatal = 'Prenatal' if self.is_prenatal else 'Postpartum'
            return f'{prenatal} Check-In: {self.timing}'
```

I'll omit the details of the `TimingMixin` for brevity, but `self.timing` is basically a string like `"0-4 weeks"` composed from the `min_weeks` and `max_weeks` fields.

The result of this, however, is that the filtering does not exactly correspond to what the user sees. Consider this example:

[image]

Here, the first entry in the list entitled "Postpartum Check-In: 0 weeks" is an automatically generated 'title'. So if I search for "Postpartum" in the search bar and press Enter, I get only one result:

[image]

whereas I would expect two results. (Incidentally, there is also an `OrderingMixin` to sort the results alphabetically by title, which is also not working for the same reason).

In order to fix this, I would like to add a field `'str'` to the queryset which contains the string representation of the object.

Following the comment in [How can i get the string representation from queryset in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012470/how-can-i-get-the-string-representation-from-queryset-in-django), I looked into [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation), but I wasn't able to find exactly what I was looking for. I would like something like

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(str=str(object))
```

so that after that I could add `Q(str__icontains=query)` to the filter. I'm not sure whether this is possible, however, because the aggregation functions like `Count()` are general database functions which don't really 'know about' Python's string representation of the model.

How can I achieve filtering the results by their actual string representation? (I would preferably like to do this by annotating the `queryset` because that would work for the `OrderingMixin` as well).

Comment: You can't do this.  The string representation is evaluated in Python in the `__str__` method, so there is no way to query this at the database level. If you need to be able to do this sort of thing then you should consider storing the string as a field in the database.